# How to create job in Quartz.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I am creating an application in MVC Web API with .NET framework 4.8 to schedule job using Quartz.Net.
Here is my code:

```
public class PrintOneTimeJob : IJob
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides printing facility
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IPrintingService _PrintingService = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependecny injection for the PrintingService
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="printingService"></param>
    public PrintOneTimeJob(IPrintingService printingService)
    {
        _PrintingService = printingService;
    }
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var printJob = _PrintingService.Print();            
    }
}

public class PrintScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<PrintOneTimeJob>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
        .RepeatForever())
        .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
   PrintScheduler.Start();
}
```

But when I run or debug my code it comes until the PrintScheduler.Start() but does not goes into the Execute() method of the PrintOneTimeJob class. And does not fire the job at all. I would appreciate any suggestion on this.

Comment: Just a guess, move `scheduler.Start();` as the last thing - after you scheduled the job.

Comment: I have tried that. But not working.

Comment: does `scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)` return a Task ?